# What account privleges should I give to my TFSBuild account?

Tags: tfs, permissions

I have a separate server that runs tfs build.

I created an account that will run the tfs build service.

I am getting an error because it says it can't access the drop folder.

what permissions do I have to give the tfs build service account?  I believe it has to be apart of some tfs specific groups?

**Update**

I decided just to use the tfsservice account on the domain...

I added the TFSService account using LogonAs for the TFSBuild service, I am getting a 'could not start team foundation build service on local computer' Error 5 access is denied.

I am using mydomain/tfsservice as the account name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the build is actually finishing except the final copy task, simply add the TFSBuild account to the drop location's folder for full control.  This will expose the smallest portion of the fs as possible.

Comment: now i'm trying to use the tfsservice account, but getting access is denied.